# Beginner mode for low reputation users

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, new-users, unanswered-questions

I have been using SO for a while now, and only recently registered myself. But something that bothers me is people who ask questions and then don't accept an answer. Now, I know this is a very robust problem, but I propose something which might help the whole situation.

Many people create user accounts here, or ask questions without full accounts and then either just copy-paste the answer and leave, or say "thank you" and leave. Without ever accepting an answer.

What I propose is for any "new" accounts to have a "beginner mode" something like this idea: (highlighted)

> When a "new" user comes to an answer to his question, he will be asked
>   "did this answer your question?" either under/above/instead of
>   comments. And he will be shown two buttons "yes" and "no"

This way it's much more intuitive for new users to the site who want to simply ask a question, but don't understand the convention of accepting answers.

Pressing "no" could bring them to the comment box, so they can clarify or whatever, while pressing "yes" will mark the answer as accepted.

Of course, this "beginner mode" could do other things, but I am specifically frustrated with the lack of accepted answers by new users.

Comment: For your information, [voting is different on Meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences): *On Meta Stack Overflow, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness.*

Comment: I actually prefer newbies to don't accept answers (unless they are really wanting to be an active user and improve SO). Since most of them will just mark the first one that worked and never come back again to change it to the best answer. Pushing new users to accept answers without knowing how the system works usually is counterproductive for everyone.

Answer (score 14):

Accepting answers is an entirely optional activity.  Nobody is required to accept answers.

That's all.

Comment: that is entirely correct. and its not forcing anyone to accept any answer, but when a new user will mouse over an answer, he will be asked "did this answer your question?" very simple and straightforward, the little white "v" on the side of the answer is not obvious to new users as a button to press for accepting an answer.

Comment: The system already nudges users in a couple of places to accept answers if they find them useful. You can also link [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if the user has a zero accept rate and clearly doesn't understand how to do it.

Comment: there is already in place a system much like the one i am suggesting which asks users "Was this post useful to you?" and provides two buttons "yes" and "no" why not have this apear for "beginner mode" users as "Did this answer your question?" only maybe slightly more noticeable.

Comment: If you do add the link of @RobertHarvey though, keep it an informative message. Please don't tell the OP he **has to** accept an answer or increase his accept rate. Tell him he technically could accept it, should he be unaware of this.

Comment: @InbarRose Yes, but that system is for unregistered users, and doesn't confer any reputation points.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thats why i said something similar to that system.

Comment: To clarify: The "Yes" and "No" system is for new users to the site who do not participate in the voting or points system. These are casual users who are not registered, and may constitute 80 to 90% of the traffic to the website. The "yes" and "no" buttons have an entirely different purpose than the voting system proper; while the voting system serves to vet questions and answers by registered participants, the yes and no system seeks to find out whether the material on the website is useful to the larger outside Internet community. In short, there are two different purposes.